# Add 8 to the entered number and then divide it by 3. Now, the modulus of that number is taken with 5 and then multiply the resultant value by 5

Tags: c

I tried with assignment operators and it worked..,but this is not running...

```
int n;
printf("Enter a 4 digit number\n");    
scanf("%d", &n);  
float i;  
i = (((n + 8)/3)%5)*5;  
printf("%f\n", i);
```

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: whats wrong in this code??? the question is:Write a program to enter a 4 digit number from keyboard. Add 8 to the number and then divide it by 3. Now, the modulus of that number is taken with 5 and then multiply the resultant value by 5. Display the final result.

Comment: what does not running mean. what is your input, output and expected output. These are all details that should be in the question. Also the title should be a general problem statement and the details should be written in the body.

Comment: Maybe you should take the [tour] and check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better understanding of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your values in the formular are integers. So integer arithmetic is used.

That means if you divide 11 by 3 you just get 3 because integers do not have decimals. And this continues through your whole formula.

You could cast n to float like this: `((float)n+8)...`

Or you could just make a part of the caluclation a float literal `n+8.0f` this way floating point arithmetics are used.

But you get a problem with the modulo as it is not defined for floating points.

So if you want to do a correct division you need the result in float but as modulo expects integers this is not possible. So without further clarification you either get a "wrong" result because you use integer arithmetics or you have a problem with modulo.

Comment: solved!! thanks sir!! should i delete this question now??

Comment: @professional_noob No, you can upvote the answers that helped you and even mark an answer by clicking on the gray check mark below the votes. But only if that really was the answer for your problem. If you found another answer for yourself you can post it here(maybe you have to wait a bit until you can do that) and mark this as the answer. And you could improve the question and title to be easier to understand.